# how to use the datareader across multiple functions in a single .net web page

Tags: .net, datareader

Is it better to declare the datareader as public or declare as local to each and every function in which we use the datareader in a .net page?

Comment: I'd tend towards local, but more information about your page would help with the decision (and justification).

Comment: this is not the answer you want but, you should consider looking at some sort of Data Layer like nHibernate or some thing like it, that way you would have you data stored in some sort of typed data container and have no need to pass the datareader around!

Comment: I keep getting a get ordinal error for pkey value in a vb.net function in code-behind at code dbReader While dbReader.Read If (IsDBNull(dbReader.Item("pkey"))) Then Exit While End If

Comment: @sony, better add a code fragment to your question. It is not as clear as you seem to think.

Comment: public dbReader as system.data.IDataReader Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load dim dbReader as system.data.IDataReader code GetProcessTeam() end sub private sub GetProcessTeam() dim dbReader as system.data.IDataReader dbReader = DAL.GetProcessTeamOrderByName(ClientKey) While dbReader.Read If (IsDBNull(dbReader.Item("pkey"))) Then Exit While End If dbReader.Close() dbReader.Dispose() dbReader = Nothing End Sub I believe the datareaders cause get ordinal error for "pkey"

Comment: @Sony: there is an `Edit` link below your question. And after you used that there are some buttons to help you formatting.

Comment: Seems to be continued here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619608/getting-index-out-of-range-exception-could-where-the-problem-in-the-code-is