# getting index out of range exception could where the problem in the code is

Tags: vb.net, unhandled-exception

```
dbReader = DAL.GetCaseSumCasesAssnCtrlMgmtCtrlChargeCodesLeftJoin(ClientKey, txtCaseNumber.Text)
If dbReader.Read Then
Try
  txtmgm.Text = dbReader.Item("MgmtCtrlpKey")
  HoldMGMKey = dbReader.Item("AssnCtrlpKey")
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

the exception is thrown at "AssnCtrlpkey"

Comment: I am getting the index out of range exception at "Assnctrlpkey" line ,but when try to execute the sql query for that line it fetches the column, I don't know exactly at which line I need to check

Comment: we took a legacy code. This code throws these index out of range exceptions , my job is to fix these. And I really do not get a clue from where to start. The above one I posted is one among those errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your dbReader doesn't have the column you're requesting ("AssnCtrlpKey"). Check your database query for that column.

Your question is sufficiently vague, however, that it's a shot in the dark.

Comment: I checked executing the sql query in the stored procedure. I get the column at runtime. It is in some cases where it throws the error saying index is out of range.

Comment: it is IDatareader and declared as public in partial Class A (A is random name of the class.) in Namespace B.

Comment: It seems clear that the column isn't there, or you're using some implementation of IDataReader that doesn't do what it's supposed to. It's clear from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a8yx17k.aspx that Item(string) throws IndexOutOfRangeException when "No column with the specified name was found."

Comment: Ok what should I start to check. I checked the datareaders are being used a lot on the page to read the data.So initially I saw a single datareader is declared as public on top of the page and that is being called when needed and closed appropritately, but it doesn't seem to me as a best practice ,this might be reason for these kind of errors. I declared the same reader as local to each function in which it is being used.